# How to hide & show Panels on button click using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The code I wrote so far runs smoothly, but when I use it on the master page it doesn't show the expected behavior. The panel does not hide back on the master page.

**What am I doing wrong ? How can I make the hide&show panel work on my master page ?**

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'>
    </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $("#btn1").click(function (evt) {
                 evt.preventDefault();
                 $('#panel1').slideUp('slow');
                 $('#panel2').slideDown('slow');
             });

             $("#Button1").click(function (evt) {
                 evt.preventDefault();
                 $('#panel2').slideUp('slow');
                 $('#panel1').slideDown('slow');
             });
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1" Style="visibility: visible;">
            <h2>
                This is panel 1</h2>
          
             <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Change Password" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="panel2" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
            <h2>
                This is panel 2.</h2>
          
            <input type="button" id="Button1" value="Cancel" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You already have an initial behaviour caused by the inline styles. Are you sure you need them?

Comment: Please to edit this question, it lacks some precisions

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

What I have done is, placed the panels in a separate div.

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    $('#panel2').slideDown('slow');
    $('#panel1').slideUp('slow');
});

$("#Button1").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#panel2').slideUp('slow');
    $('#panel1').slideDown('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1" Style="visibility: visible;">
        <h2>
                    This is panel 1</h2>

        <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Change Password" />
    </asp:Panel>

</div>
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="panel2" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
        <h2>
                    This is panel 2.</h2>

        <input type="button" id="Button1" value="Cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but its not working when i use it in master page.